# Neo4j configuration file

Tags: path, neo4j

I've tried to run a simple example "Hello World" with Neo4j but I don't know how to modify the configuration file.
I don't know what to put as a parameter for

```
"GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
                                           .newEmbeddedDatabase(" ..... ");"
```

and what other modification do I have to make. Do I have to put the org.neo4j.server.database.location from the neo4j-server.properties?

But first, do I have to run the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either put in the path from org.neo4j.server.database.location in the neo4j-server.properties file which will allow you to access the same database referred to when you run the server/webadmin.
Or you can put in the path to any directory that you have access to and your database will be created there.
You should not run the server since the above code uses Neo4j in embedded mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried it before (to put that path from the org.neo4j.server.database.location) but when I try to output the property from a node it says: " Non clean shutdown detected on log .. " even though this method is called  -  " graphDB.shutdown(); " and graphDB is " GraphDatabaseService graphDB = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("data/graph.db"); " I've also tried with the full path "D:/neo4j/data/graph.db".  Thanks again!

Comment: It finally worked. I'm new at this. Thanks for answering me! :)